# Intelliji debug not working with testng maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, testng

When I try to run `TestNG` suite in `IntelliJ` using a `maven` goal :

`mvn clean verify -Denv =dev` ,

Then debugging is not working ! It does not stop at the break points . Please can someone help me to resolve this !

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [TestNG debugging tests](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html)

> You can use the `maven.surefire.debug` property to debug your forked tests remotely, The tests will automatically pause and await a remote `debugger` on `port 5005`

Your `maven` goal has to be changed to `mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug clean verify -Denv =dev`.

Using `IntelliJ` remote configuration option debugging can be performed.